# keras implementation of a parallel convolution layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, caffe

learning keras and cnn in general, so tried to implement a network i found in a paper, in it there is a parallel convolution layer of 3 convs where each conv apply a different filter on the input, here how i tried to solve it:

```
inp = Input(shape=(32,32,192))

conv2d_1 = Conv2D(
        filters = 32,
        kernel_size = (1, 1),
        strides =(1, 1),
        activation = 'relu')(inp)
conv2d_2 = Conv2D(
        filters = 64,
        kernel_size = (3, 3),
        strides =(1, 1),
        activation = 'relu')(inp)
conv2d_3 = Conv2D(
        filters = 128,
        kernel_size = (5, 5),
        strides =(1, 1),
        activation = 'relu')(inp)
out = Concatenate([conv2d_1, conv2d_2, conv2d_3])
model.add(Model(inp, out))
```

-this gives me the following err : `A Concatenate layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis....etc`.

- i tried solving it by adding the arg `input_shape = inp` in every Conv2D function, now it gives me `Cannot iterate over a tensor with unknown first dimension.`

ps : the paper writers implemented this network with caffe, the input to this layer is (32,32,192) and the output after the merge is (32,32,224).

Comment: Your kernel sizes are different, hence the output of conv1 is 32x32x32, conv2 is 30x30x64, conv3 is 28x28x128.

Comment: aramakus, i understand, but the output is (*,*,224) like 32+64+128, so they must have merged them somehow, that is what i want to know

Comment: aramakus, so if the problem is in the x and y only could it be solved with padding, if  the z should also be the same in Concatenate(), is there any other way to merge (32x32x32)+(32x32x64)+(32x32x128) into (32x32x224) ?

Comment: By default, Cancatenate stacks inputs on top of each other along the depth (last dimension). But in your code without padding it cannot do so as x and y are different. I've posted a code, it is easier to see than to tell.

Comment: aramakus, thank you, now i understand how it works, :) y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you add the padding to match the array shapes, `Concatenate` will not be able to match them. Try running this

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Concatenate

inp = Input(shape=(32,32,192))

conv2d_1 = Conv2D(
        filters = 32,
        kernel_size = (1, 1),
        strides =(1, 1),
        padding = 'SAME',
        activation = 'relu')(inp)
conv2d_2 = Conv2D(
        filters = 64,
        kernel_size = (3, 3),
        strides =(1, 1),
        padding = 'SAME',
        activation = 'relu')(inp)
conv2d_3 = Conv2D(
        filters = 128,
        kernel_size = (5, 5),
        strides =(1, 1),
        padding = 'SAME',
        activation = 'relu')(inp)
out = Concatenate()([conv2d_1, conv2d_2, conv2d_3])

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)

model.summary()
```